# Android studio confusing method parameter

Tags: android

When I used android studio version 2.1.2 and use method, parameter is very clear for me to understand this method in version 2.1.2.
but when I update android studio to version 2.1.3, the method parameter make me confusing.

Can you help me how to fix it or how can I get back old-version?

Comment: I think you maybe missed the `Sources for Android SDK`, you can `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` and download the sources from the platform you need. And delete your codes, write them again, the parameter will appears. Hope it helps.

Comment: :( it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the the simplest way is to unInstall 2.1.3 and install 2.1.2 again.